# Is this impossible with xpath?

Tags: xml, xpath

Is it possible with xpath to get the result transformed somehow, just like it can be done with SQL?

Given the following:

```
<a>
  <b x="1" y="2" z="3">
  <b x="2" y="2" z="3">
</a>
```

For example if I wanted to get all b nodes, but i don't want the z attribute to be part of the the results.

Or another thing which Iam thinking about is to receive all y nodes multiplied with a factor something like that /a/b[(@y*2)] which seems not to be possible, at least I don't know how to write it.

Comment: No. What exactly are you trying to achieve? Why do you want this?

Comment: I just want to understand what the limits of xpath are.

Comment: Good question (+1). See my answer for a simple and powerful XSLT solution. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, with XPath, you can only select some nodes from the document. To do this, you could use XQuery (which is a superset of XPath) or XSLT.

Answer (score 3):

As pointed in the answer of @svick, an XPath expression can select a set of nodes from XML document(s), but it cannot alter the XML document(s) or create new document(s).

Here is an XSLT transformation that produces a new XML document in which the `z` attributes are omitted and the `y` attributes are multiplied by 2.

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
 xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
 <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>
 <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

 <xsl:template match="node()|@*">
  <xsl:copy>
   <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
  </xsl:copy>
 </xsl:template>

 <xsl:template match="@z"/>

 <xsl:template match="@y">
   <xsl:attribute name="y">
     <xsl:value-of select="2* ."/>
   </xsl:attribute>
 </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**when this transformation is applied on the provided XML document** (corrected to be well-formed):

```
<a>
  <b x="1" y="2" z="3"/>
  <b x="2" y="2" z="3"/>
</a>
```

**the wanted, correct result is produced**:

```
<a>
   <b x="1" y="4"/>
   <b x="2" y="4"/>
</a>
```

**The easiness and power of this solution are due to using one of the most powerful XSLT design pattern: the use of the identity rule and its overriding** with specific templates only for nodes that must be processed in a specific way.

Answer (score 1):

With xslt you can use xsl:element to define new elements using the old ones or add attributes using xsl:attribute.

Use these to generate the elements in the way you want them from the xpath result set.